# reverse method is always false?

Tags: ruby

I don't know why this isn't working properly, it always gives me false.

More importantly is there an easy way to see line-by-line execution of the code? Something like an easy trace that would help me troubleshoot this (I tried irb, but couldn't get it to work with multiline example like this one).

```
 puts 'enter a word and I will tell you if its a palindrome or not: '
    word = gets.chomp
    backwards = word.reverse
    if word == backwards
      puts "yes, it is a palindrome!"
    else
      puts "no, #{word} is not a palindrome."
    end
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I had a typo in my word. This is working fine. I feel like an idiot. Which brings me to my second question above... a good way to trace code execution in irb or elsewhere... is that possible?

Comment: The code that you have written is working correctly for me.  What inputs have you used that gave you outputs you didn't expect?

Comment: Oops, sorry! It turns out I had a typo in my palindrome word that I was using to test this. Embarrassing!!

Comment: You might also consider `strip`ping your word, not just `chomp`ing it.

Comment: Also might want to make it case insensitive... `if word.downcase == word.downcase.reverse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pry gem is an excellent debugging tool.

https://github.com/pry/pry

Install it by typing on the command line...

```
gem install pry
```

Then in your code at the point you want to halt execution, enter this line

```
require 'pry'; binding.pry
```

You can then inspect all variables, even change them if you want, and type 'exit' when you're ready to resume.

If you do `require 'pry'` at the beginning of your program, you can just do `binding.pry` where you need to halt... in that case you don't need the two-command expression I used above.